# Laravel Project showed sqlstate hy000 error 2002 connection refused error after one day on live aws server

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am hosting my laravel website on AWS Server, after I uploaded a new version using Elastic Bean Stalk it worked fine, but after 10 - 12 hours suddenly it showed the below error, at home page and my site was not working.

> sqlstate hy000 error 2002 connection refused

I double checked the .env file of my website but everything is correct, I just cleared the cache and config using the artisan commands and then it started working again. Can any one suggest what was the cause of that error and how can I prevent it from happening again in future? TIA

Comment: Is your database part of the EB environment or is it separate i.e. a separate RDS instance or on a different server altogether?

Comment: @Rwd It is part of my EBS. ( RDS )

Comment: I could be very wrong about the following, however, AFAIK, when an EB instance need to be provisioned again for certain changes it will replace the instance. In these cases the database will be created again as well which will more than likely result in new credentials. Since these credential are added as environment variables the config will need to be cleared whenever this occurs. One option to get around this is to have a db instance that isn't directly tied to your EB environment. I would hope that there are more elegant solutions but hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Rwd thanks. So will my website go down every time I upload a new version? If  ues then what is the best solution except the database outside the EBS.? Thanks btw

Comment: @Rwd but as you stated it will result in new credentials but I didnt change anythin in my .env file all info (username, password, host etc) are same as previous. I just cleared the cache, config and then rebuilt.

Comment: No, it shouldn't necessarily go down when you make a deployment, at least not according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rollingupdates.html, however, it's my understanding that (which again I could be very wrong about as it's only something I've recently started looking into myself) the instances will have security updates applied to them which can cause them to be recreated.

Comment: Another post which might be worth a look is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html.I said it might result in new credentials. Which makes sense if your having to clear your config to be able to connect to the new database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209425/discussion-between-faisal-shani-and-rwd).